# The Strange Conversation

Tags: lateral-thinking, situation, mystery

One morning, I was riding along my bicycle around town and I stopped outside the shopping center as there were 2 old-persons, one man and one woman (let's call them A and B) standing outside and talking, both having bags of groceries, and rather having a really strange conversation :-

> A :- Did you hear the news about a house that got burned down last night?

> B :- Yes. A woman died in the fire. I wonder how it got started.

> A :- It was arson who started the fire.

> B :- What really, that's scary. I am worried, aren't you?

> A :- Do the police know who did it?

> B :- I don't think so.

This conversation gave me the creeps and then I cycled away thinking about it. After a moment, I immediately realised something which frightened me even more and I called the police.

What frightened me even more, as I was cycling away?

Comment: rot13(Ernq @hfre39583'f nafjre naq lbh jvyy haqrefgnaq. Qrhfbiv'f nafjre nyfb cebivqrf na nggnpx ba guvf glcrf bs zlfgrel ceboyrzf)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that

> A says "it was *arson* who started the fire", not *an arsonist*.

I'm guessing you realised

> That they were actually saying *our son*.

Comment: Correct, that's the answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

Is it that:

> If B saw the news and didn't know that it was arson, that means the news never said that it was arson. Since A *did* know that, it means that A must have been the culprit.

(This is making some assumptions:)

> ...specifically, that either there was only one place where the news was broken, or all of the news sources had the same information. This might not be the case if, say, A saw later news after some investigation had been done, while B hadn't seen the version with more information.

Comment: Nice try, but if you read the other answer it is that one which is correct. It can sometimes be tricky if you read the question. +1 never the less.